# Suppose some hash family H satisfies $$Pr_{h_{\in_{R}} H}[h(x_1) = h(x_2)] = \frac{1}{|Y|}$$ Does it mean H is 2 universal?

Tags: hash

Suppose some hash family H satisfies $$Pr_{h_{\in_{R}} H}[h(x_1) = h(x_2)] = \frac{1}{|Y|}$$ Does it mean H is 2 universal?

The converse is true, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.